# Can command line arguments in ruby be erased?

Tags: ruby, unix, argv

For security reasons I would like to remove the command line arguments after parsing them:

```
login.rb --user me --password wombats
```

I've tried ARGV.clear and $*.clear

changes to neither ARGV or $* are reflected in ps

Comment: I've offered a possible answer below, although another approach would be to not accept passwords on the command-line at all but instead prompt the user to enter their password via `STDIN`.

Comment: Would clearing the terminal after the login be sufficient? If so, you could use `system 'clear'` after parsing your command line arguments.

Comment: Some systems let you remove the command-line arguments. It's possible to rename the `$PROGRAM_NAME` global at runtime and try to fool `ps`, but the command will remain in the history buffer. And, if using `sudo`, the commands will be tracked.

Comment: You may consider changing the idea of the problem, such as providing a file name or path where the password is stored, and reading that rather than providing it directly from the command line.  This will leave the history intact, but not expose the password.  Of course, normal file permission precautions should be taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the name of the Ruby process (as shown by `ps(1)`) by changing the `$PROGRAM_NAME` variable. Here's an example program which intentionally loops, as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts $PROGRAM_NAME
$PROGRAM_NAME = "a ruby process"

loop { }
```

When it run it like so:

```
$ ./loop.rb password
./loop.rb
```

And it shows "a ruby process" in `ps`:

```
$ ps aux | grep ruby
stuart         85292  98.9  0.1  2439468   4340 s004  R+    8:43PM   0:02.96 a ruby process  
stuart         85341   0.0  0.0  2432768    600 s011  S+    8:43PM   0:00.00 grep --color ruby
```

So you could use the `$PROGRAM_NAME` variable to change exactly how the process is shown via `ps`.